# Is there a way to integrate the Word online application as a viewer in my own web app?

Tags: ms-word, office365

It is not possible to iframe the Word online application as iframing has apparently been set to disabled.

Comment: Did you check if there is an API or docuemntation from the vendor? If the "iframing" is disallowed by the vendor, it might cause severe legal hazards, when asking coders for help on this one. In case, the vendor explicitly allows it but does not show how, many here will be happy to help, as coders do. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple iframing of the World Online editor is indeed not allowed. However, there is an extensive framework aimed specifically at integrating Word Online in your own application that's called the 'WOPI Framework'. It requires a little bit more work to setup but it will actually allow you to do exactly that. See the documentation [here](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).